# osgeolive permission issue when adding jar modules to geoserver

Tags: linux, geoserver, osgeo

I am trying to copy the imagepyramid plugin into my geoserver and the system just won't let me do this. I am logged in as admin

```
user@osgeolive:/usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.1.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib$ sudo chown -R atgis /usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.1.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib
user@osgeolive:/usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.1.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib$ cp /home/user/downloads/gt-imagepyramid-8.4.jar gt-imagepyramid-8.4.jar
cp: cannot create regular file `gt-imagepyramid-8.4.jar': Permission denied
user@osgeolive:/usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.1.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib$ mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory `test': Permission denied
user@osgeolive:/usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.1.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib$ cd ..
user@osgeolive:/usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.1.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF$ chmod 777 lib
chmod: changing permissions of `lib': Operation not permitted
user@osgeolive:/usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.1.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Stop the geoserver service.
2. Check if you have permission to write into geoserver folder.

   $ ls -all /usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.1.3/webapps/

If you don't have permission to write :

```
$ chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.1.3/webapps/geoserver
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: @GeorgeC stop the geoserver was the solution?

Comment: nope I had stopped geoserver earlier as well. The solution was just to run ">>sudo cp ..." and not ">>sudo chown -R"